# How to open file in CMD (using wild-cards ? or *)

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd

I have a little problem.

How I can open file in CMD using `?` or `*` in file name?
I have this line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /n /s /h /t "FILE_PATH\FILE_NAME.pdf" "ADRESS"
```

I know some name from this file, ex.: `1234.pdf`; sometimes this file changed name, ex.: `1234A.pdf`, `1234B.pdf`, `1234C.pdf` - how I can send file with expression (`?` or `*`) in file name? Any sugestion?

Comment: These characters (`?`, `*`) are called wild-cards. And you are not using DOS but CMD (Windows command prompt); DOS is an OS from the 1980s. Anyway, when your application does not support them in its command line arguments, you can use a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to resolve the wild-cards: `for %I in ("D:\container\1234?.pdf") do "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /n /s /h /t "%~I" "ADDRESS"` (double the `%`-signs in a batch file)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just find the files related to starting regular expression "1234" and ending with any other combination of letter by first using the "dir" command as the following:

syntax: dir 1234*.txt (or) if file format is not known 1234*.* that gives all the list of files in the current directory.

then you can directly open the file by typing the file name adding an extension to it

for example: 1234bac.txt

Comment: I know, but this script is for automatic find file and send to printer. Your soluion is for manual check and write.

Comment: Assign a COM port to your printer first.
Open Start → Control Panel → Devices and Printers.
Right-click the PRINTER which prints and select Printer Properties.
In the Ports tab, assign an unused port from COM1: to COM4: to your printer.
If you chose, e.g., COM3, print using the following command:
print /d:COM3 1234*.pdf

Comment: The same is for network printer? This is not in my house :( I do this, becouse i want to improve my work.

Comment: Yeah. All plays in the same!